# How could I get only specified columns instead of the full object? Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this is my first time asking something here and I hope I do it alright.
Im new to Laravel and I just know the basics of Eloquent, what I am trying to do is a game recommendator, so, in order to do so, the user sets a genre and I want to return all the games with this genre.

I am using whereHas as I am using a many to many relationship, this is my code:

```
public function searchByPreferences(){
    $genre_id = request('genre');
    $games = Game::whereHas('genres', function (Builder $query) use($genre_id) {
                $query->where('genre_id',$genre_id);
            })->get();

    dd($games);
}
```

So, this returns the games with all their data, and what I want is to only get an array of their IDs so I can make the petition of the game by id later. Thank you in andvance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pluck() function to get list of ids as below :

```
public function searchByPreferences(){
            $genre_id = request('genre');
            $games = Game::whereHas('genres', function (Builder $query) use($genre_id) {
                        $query->where('genre_id',$genre_id);

                    })->pluck('id')->all();

            dd($games);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!, this is way better than the foreach + array_push I had

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution and it's pretty easy.

You can specify the column giving the get() a parameter like this:

```
    public function searchByPreferences(){
    $genre_id = request('genre');
    $games = Game::whereHas('genres', function (Builder $query) use($genre_id) {
                $query->where('genre_id',$genre_id);

            })->get('id');

    dd($games);
}
```